# swift 3 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key startDate

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, date

I'm getting this error in line/code that I'm using to return a grouped events. I read a lot of this error, but found only posts that explains this error about buttons, text labels or views. Is it wrong syntax or what?

```
class someManager: NSObject {

  func eventFrom(from startDate: NSDate, to endDate: NSDate) -> [Any] {

    let groupedEvents = NSMutableArray()  
      // some code

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "startDate", ascending: true)
    return groupedEvents.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]) // error here
  }
}

*/
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDate *startDate;
// cmd + press on startDate
/*
```

Full error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[AppName.EventListController 0x170225340 valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key startDate.'

All EventListController:

```
    class EventListController: NSObject {

    var AstartDate = Date()
    var Aevents = NSArray()

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all objects in `groupedEvents` are of that class? Could you give us that class name and the whole error message?

Comment: edited my previous post

Comment: NSMutableArray elements or someManager does not have any "startDate"

Comment: So should I change the type of groupedEvents to date? How Adolfo mentioned it.

Comment: @NiravD If I'm right, I'm getting it from EKEvent. But "startDate' as variable I have all over the project. Even in the same "someManager", but in other method.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mutable array contains object of NSDate type.  If you want to sort this array you can apply the `sort` function from Array Swift class

```
var groupEvent: [Date] = [ Date() ]

groupEvent.sort(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

or

```
groupEvent.sort()
```

Comment: Should I really change the type to Date, cause I need to add some object to it and check if its empty?

Comment: You don't need to check if array is empty.